# How to initially mute videos?

Tags: video.js

I have tried:

```
videojs("cats").ready(function(){
myPlayer.volume(0);
});
```

... but it did not work. I searched here and through the documents and am not finding the answer, or using the code correctly.

Comment: Do you want muted (0% volume) or quiet (50%) volume? The title does not ask the same question as the code.

Comment: Sorry, I was up a little too late. :) Yes, even at 0 or 0.0 it is still at full volume. Is there a full example of this somewhere?

Comment: How about [providing a complete example that demonstrates how you're actually using this snippet?](http://sscce.org) http://jsfiddle.net is a nice tool for this.

Answer (score 18):

might be a bit late.

In your javascript, try:

```
myPlayer.muted(true);
```

Comment: plus one for answering the videoJS component

Answer (score 15):

Okay so the answer is easy:

just add:   muted    to the  tag, such as:

```
 <video id="cats" class="video-js vjs-fullscreen vjs-default-skin" muted autoplay controls loop preload="auto" width="600" height="400"
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="x.webm" type='video/webm' /> 
  </video>
```

Comment: The answer is for a video tag, and not videoJS

Answer (score 6):

When you init the player, you can set muted to true.

```
videojs("cats", { muted: true });
```

Answer (score 4):

There'r few ways to set Mute on VideoJS.

```
 {muted: true} OR this.volume(0) OR "muted" attribute in a video tag
```

**Sample below:**

```
  var setupOpt = {
      'techOrder': ["html5", "flash"],
      'muted'    : true, //OR YOU CAN ADD MUTE Attr.
      'controls' : true,
      'autoplay' : true,
      'preload'  : 'auto',
      'height'   : '500px',
      'width'    : '500px',
      'poster'   : "Url for poster"
  };

  videojs("my-video", setupOpt , function() {
    var player = this;
        player.src({ src: "URL!", type: 'TYPE!'});
        player.volume(0); //Volume range 0.0 to 1 (0.0, 0.1, 0.2 ...)
    // });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code `myPlayer.volume(0.5);` will not mute the video. You need to change that to:

```
myPlayer.volume(0);
```

From the [documentation](http://www.videojs.com/docs/api/): "0 is off (muted), 1.0 is all the way up, 0.5 is half way."

Comment: Yes, even at 0 or 0.0 it is still at full volume. Is there a full example of this somewhere? I have searched all over but cannot find it. I am sure this is simple but I cannot get it to initiate. Thank you.

Comment: I'm still searching this myself

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but I think the solution is quite easy. Change your code from `myPlayer` to `this`. Should look like this:

```
videojs("cats").ready(function(){
    this.volume(0);
});
```

This is untested, but it should work, I think. Even if you had a variable `myPlayer` that takes the player, it will contain it only after having set the `.ready()` callback, so in the callback, the variable won't be holding your player.

Maybe my explanation is wrong, but you could try this... ;-)

EDIT: Just saw some of the other answers, that should also work.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, This worked for me.. After Banging my Head. 
Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code is that the myPlayer variable is not defined

```
videojs("cats", {}, function(){
          var myPlayer = this;
          myPlayer.volume(0);
});
```